# Fill color not showing appropriately in folium?

Tags: python, python-3, folium

The following code should have shown different colored circles in a map. But my result was circles with no color at all.

```
import folium
import pandas

data=pandas.read_csv("Volcanoes.txt")
lat = list(data["LAT"])
lon = list(data["LON"])
elev = list(data["ELEV"])

def color_producer(elevation):
    if elevation < 1000:
        return 'green'
    elif 1000 <= elevation < 3000:
        return 'orange'
    else:
        return 'red'
map = folium.Map(location=[38.58, -99.09], zoom_start=6, tiles="Mapbox Bright")
fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")
for lt, ln, el in zip(lat, lon, elev):
    fg.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lt, ln], radius = 6, popup=str(el)+" m",
    fill_color=color_producer(el), color = 'grey', fill_opacity=0.7))
map.add_child(fg)
map.save("Map1.html")
```

Can you show me where did I did wrong?

[image: Screenshot of the output]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According the [documentation](http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/docs-master/modules.html?#folium.vector_layers.path_options), when you're creating a `CircleMarker` object the `fill` parameter defaults to `False`. Try explicitly setting it to `True` in your code:

```
#...

for lt, ln, el in zip(lat, lon, elev):
    cm = folium.CircleMarker(location=[lt, ln],
                            radius = 6,
                            popup=str(el)+" m",
                            fill=True, # Set fill to True
                            fill_color=color_producer(el),
                            color = 'grey',
                            fill_opacity=0.7)
    fg.add_child(cm)

#...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition

```
import folium
import pandas

data=pandas.read_csv("Volcanoes.txt")
lat = list(data["LAT"])
lon = list(data["LON"])
elev = list(data["ELEV"])

def color_producer(elevation):
    if elevation < 1000:
        return 'green'
    elif 1000 <= elevation or elevation< 3000:# Check here i too had same problem
        return 'orange'
    else:
        return 'red'
map = folium.Map(location=[38.58, -99.09], zoom_start=6, tiles="Mapbox Bright")
fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")
for lt, ln, el in zip(lat, lon, elev):
    fg.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lt, ln], radius = 6, popup=str(el)+" m",
    fill_color=color_producer(el), color = 'grey', fill_opacity=0.7))
map.add_child(fg)
map.save("Map1.html")
```

Comment: It would be `and` not `or`.